# Estimating a model of the form z=k(x^a)(y^b) in R

Tags: r, regression

Given arrays of data x, y, z I need to estimate the constants k, a and b in

```
z = k x^a y^b
```

Some of the z data contains zeros, which makes taking logs of both sides difficult.  Following discussion on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89722/fitting-a-log-or-generalized-linear-model) I think I need to fit a generalized linear model with a poisson link function.  But how to express this in R?  I have tried

```
glm(z ~ x*y,data,family=poisson)
```

But this outputs estimates for x, y and x*y separately, so I suspect they don't relate to the power terms I want to estimate.  Meanwhile

```
glm(log z ~ log x + log y, data, family=gaussian)
```

Complains of NaN/inf in fit, presumably because of the zeros in z.

How does I encode this model correctly?

Comment: Although you are sort of asking a programming question you really need to figure out your model first and it sounds like you're sort of just kind of maybe thinking that might be the right thing to do... probably .  Post to cross validated to get a better understanding of the model you should fit and how to actually interpret the model before coming here with any programming issues.  Also is your response a count (or does it just take values on integers)?

Comment: I think I know the kind of model I want to fit, it's a matter of expressing it in R.  The response variable is a count of events over areas although due to sparse sampling it will contain zeros for some areas.

Comment: Worrying about the response being 0 so you can't take the log of both sides implies you don't fully understand the model you're trying to fit.  I'm not trying to be mean - I'm just saying that I think the bigger issue is that you don't understand the model you're trying to fit.

Comment: Ok.  I think that is exactly why I'm choosing a poisson model without trying to take logs of both sides (which would be a feasible solution without zeros).  Do you have any pointers on what I should be looking for to fit my model as described?

Comment: The most straightforward approach is nonlinear regression using `nls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are (at least) 2 ways to do this. The first uses `glm(...)`.

```
fit <- glm(z~log(x)+log(y),data,family=poisson)
```

Poisson glm fits a function of the form

> z = exp[ b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub> × x<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>2</sub> × x<sub>2</sub> ]

Substituting x<sub>1</sub> = log(x), x<sub>2</sub> = log(y) gives

> z = exp[ b<sub>0</sub> + log(x<sup>b<sub>1</sub></sup>) + log(y<sup>b<sub>2</sub></sup>) ] = exp(b<sub>0</sub>) × x<sup>b<sub>1</sub></sup> × y<sup>b<sub>2</sub></sup>

from which we can see by inspection that k = exp(b<sub>0</sub>), a = b<sub>1</sub>, and b = b<sub>2</sub>. In R code:

```
set.seed(1)
# generate some "data"
s <- seq(1,10,.2)
x <- sample(s,25)
y <- sample(s,25)
z <- 2*x^2.5*y^-1.5+rnorm(25,0,5)
z[z<0] <- 0  # OP's data has zeros
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
# generalized linear model
fit.glm <- glm(z~log(x)+log(y),df,family=poisson)
summary(fit.glm)
# ... 
#
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)  0.65005    0.24973   2.603  0.00924 ** 
# log(x)       2.51848    0.12318  20.446  < 2e-16 ***
# log(y)      -1.47706    0.05288 -27.932  < 2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
# (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
#
#     Null deviance: 1236.554  on 24  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance:   25.509  on 22  degrees of freedom
# AIC: Inf
# ...
```

Note that in this artificial example, k=2, a=2.5, and b=-1.5. Since exp(0.65) = 1.92, we can see that glm does well recovering these parameters. One problem with glm is that we are estimating log(k), not k, so if we want confidence limits on k we need another approach.

As @BenBolker says, non-linear regression is also an option. Here wee would use

```
# non-linear regression
fit.nls <- nls(z~k*x^a*y^b,df)
summary(fit.nls)
# Formula: z ~ k * x^a * y^b
#
# Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# k  1.95561    0.21705    9.01 7.77e-09 ***
# a  2.50086    0.05104   49.00  < 2e-16 ***
# b -1.45590    0.02651  -54.93  < 2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
# Residual standard error: 3.153 on 22 degrees of freedom
#
# Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.344e-07
```

The statistics of the fit are a bit easier to interpret here. Since we are estimating k directly, the CL are for k. The disadvantage of nls is that sometimes it is difficult to get convergence. Generally, one must supply starting estimates that are fairly close to the final values.

We can plot z-predicted vs. z-actual to get a sense of how good the fit(s) are. This variation on the residuals plot is helpful when there is more than one predictor. The reference line, pred = actual, represents a perfect fit.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(z,predict(fit.glm,type="response"), main="glm",ylab="pred.Z",xlab="act.Z")
abline(0,1,lty=2,col="blue")
plot(z,predict(fit.nls), main="nls",ylab="pred.Z",xlab="act.Z")
abline(0,1,lty=2,col="blue")
```

[image]

Finally, we need to check the residuals for normality using the Q-Q plot.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
resid <- residuals(fit.glm,type="response")
qqnorm(resid,main="glm")
qqline(resid, lty=2, col="blue")
resid <- residuals(fit.nls)
qqnorm(resid,main="nls")
qqline(resid, lty=2, col="blue")
```

[image]

Note that there is a greater deviation from normality than would be expected, given that the dataset was created by adding normally distributed error. This is mostly due to the addition of artificial zeros.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  Your first four lines explain the trouble I was having fitting glm poisson - i.e. I had to be explicit about logs of the predictors but not the target.  glm seems to work for me.  nls I can't get to converge, pity as that would give me the option of fixing `a==1` which makes the most structural sense for my model!  The same nls does converge in SPSS though so I have an answer now.

Comment: Ah, fixed my last point, nls converges if I set `algorithm="port"` (but with a very bad standard error for k).  This matches SPSS.

Comment: Yes `port` is a better algorithm than Newton Raphson (the default). Also, for especially difficult-to-fit models there's `nls.lm(...)` in the `minpack` package.